# Clear CrowdStrike SensorGroupingTags with Powershell

Tags: powershell

Quick explanation is that I need to reassign CrowdStrike tags locally on the hosts. I built a powershell script that stops right when the machine asks for a maintenance token. I have to run the CrowdStrike commands in command prompt, they do not work in powershell. It works until you need to enter the maintenance token, but shouldn't the variable entered earlier work? So the script is like this:

```
$maintenanceToken = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Maintenance token"
$location = Read-Host -Prompt "What location are we at today"

$cs_version = cmd.exe /c CsSensorSettings --version
  if($cs_version -Like "*6.4*") {
  Write-Host "Clearing Tags"
  $csClear = cmd.exe /c "CsSensorSettings clear --grouping-tags"
  $maintenanceToken  

  ### It works until right here, it just 
  stop Token is never entered ###

  ... more code ...}
```

I have tried doing Invoke-Command $maintenaceToken and cmd.exe $maintenanceToken. Everything I find doesn't seem to work. I am wondering if it us stuck in Command Prompt and if it is how do I get around it.

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Change line to : Write-Host "Token = " $maintenanceToken

Comment: Formatting better?